# DataGrid row tooltip

Tags: wpf, datagrid, tooltip, datagridrowheader

i have the following DataGrid and for some reason the tooltip i created for a row is not showing when i'm hovering on the row:

```
<DataGrid
                    Name="dataGrid"
                    CanUserAddRows="False"
                    CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                    CanUserReorderColumns="False"
                    GridLinesVisibility="None"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding PermissionsCollection,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    AlternatingRowBackground="{StaticResource VigilantDataGridAlternatingRowColor}"
                    ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource VigilantDataGridColumnHeader}"
                    RowHeaderWidth="0"
                    RowHeight="30"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                    SelectionMode="Single"
                    Height="536"
                    Width="700"
                    IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
                    ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True">
                    <DataGrid.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                            <EventSetter Event="MouseDown" Handler="MouseDownHandler"/>
                        </Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                            <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled" Value="True"/>
                            <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <TextBlock Text="1234"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGrid.Resources>
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

that was totaly my bad, didn't notice i had:

```
<Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False" />
```

in my DataGridRow style.